# How to completely remove Room master table (schemas) from phone

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to build a Room database in development. But after making some changes, Room keeps throwing this error:

```
Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
```

The issue is: I haven't even write to the database! So, there shouldn't be any problems because **there is no data to check integrity**.
After searching for answers on how to completely remove Room schemas from my test phone, I tried the following methods:

- Increasing the version number (Room didn't ask for migrations)
- Changing the database name
- Disable  allowBackup, fullBackupOnly and fullBackupContent from AndroidManifest.xml
- Clear application data & cache
- Uninstall application
- Delete backups on Google Drive

But Room insists that cannot verify the data integrity. What should I do?

**EDIT:** Looks like I solved the problem. I had to upgrade my database all the way to version 6! I have no idea why, but that happened. If you're making a Room database, make sure you get your schemas right, or else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your point that you haven't even written anything to the database file...
You have probably forgotten to add elements in the annotation processor of the database.
You should try to declare like this example...

@Database(entities = Vehicle.class, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class VehicleDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

//Your code here
}

P.S - If you ever upgrade version of the database then you should also use the migration. For this check offical documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions)

Answer (score 0):

I have same Problem for solved i unistall app form my emulator/phone and re-run project app.

BTW Its error generate when db schema changes.